# Incorrect memory operation?

Tags: c++, gcc

Help to find an error in this function, please.

```
wchar_t* clean(wchar_t out[], const wchar_t in[])
{
    int n = wcslen(in);
    wchar_t *str = new wchar_t[n];
    wcscpy(str, in);

    out[0] = L'\0';
    wchar_t *state;

    wchar_t *word = wcstok(str, L" ", &state);

    while (NULL != word) {
        if (wcslen(word) > 1) {
            wcscat(out, word);
            wcscat(out, L" ");
        }
        word = wcstok(NULL, L" ", &state);
    }

    delete state;
    delete[] str;
    return out;
}
```

This function get from original string words and put them in result string.
Besides function ignore multiple spaces and word from single letter.

Unfortunately, the program falls on the last lines of this function with same error(linux-3.7, gcc-4.7):

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08610338 ***
```

Explain, please, in what I was mistaken?

Comment: `str` does not contain enough space for the terminating `NULL` character.

Comment: @timrau excellent catch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Remove the `delete state;`. `state` is not a pointer to dynamic memory, as you can tell from the absence of any dynamic allocation assigned to it. It's just a pointer to somewhere inside an existing string.
2. Fix the buffer overflow with `new wchar_t[n]`; it has no space for the terminating NULL.

Comment: And fix the buffer overflow with `new wchar_t[n]` - no space for the terminating NULL.